# Attach image in Native SMS/MMS Application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, sms

i want to send an image through native application in iphone.

I have searched a lot on web but cant find anything.

is it possible with iOS?

Please do help...

Answer (score 4):

[MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the only documented API for creating SMS messages programmatically. It does not currently allow MMS but you can file a bug report for the feature request. In the meantime, you can either:

-use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://-%20%28void%29addAttachmentData%3a%28NSData%2a%29attachment%20mimeType%3a%28NSString%2a%29mimeType%20fileName%3a%28NSString%2a%29filename) which does allow image attachments via -(void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename

-or like Aurum mentioned, save the image to the photo library and instruct the user to send it with the native "Messages" app.

Comment: Has this changed since July 6th, 2011?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to do this programatically - I don't think you can. Your best bet'd be to save the image to the camera roll and tell the user to attach it. Maybe someone more experienced knows a better way of doing things.

If you just want to do it as a normal user opening the messages app, you can. Just click the little blue camera on the left hand side of the text field.